# Android map opening from intent and call dialing from intent not working after updating target version to 30 on Android 11 devices

Tags: android, android-intent, android-11

This seems like a package visibility issue as mentioned by Android
https://developer.android.com/about/versions/11/privacy/package-visibility

```
fun Activity.callPlayStoreIntent() {
    val appPackageName = this.packageName
    try {
        val uri = Uri.parse("market://details?id=$appPackageName")
        val intent = Intent(ACTION_VIEW, uri)
        startActivity(intent)
    } catch (exception: ActivityNotFoundException) {
        try {
            val uri = Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=$appPackageName")
            val intent = Intent(ACTION_VIEW, uri)
            startActivity(intent)
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
    }
}


fun Context.callFromDialer(number: String) {
    try {
        val callIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL)
        callIntent.data = Uri.parse("tel:$number")
        if (callIntent.resolveActivity(packageManager) != null) {
            startActivity(callIntent)
        }
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        e.printStackTrace()
        Toast.makeText(this, "No SIM Found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
    }
}


fun Context.intentOpenMap(
    latitude: Double,
    longitude: Double,
    label: String,
) {
    try {
        val uriBegin = "geo:$latitude,$longitude"
        val query = "$latitude,$longitude($label)"
        val encodedQuery = Uri.encode(query)
        val uriString = "$uriBegin?q=$encodedQuery&z=20"
        val uri = Uri.parse(uriString)
        val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri)
        if (intent.resolveActivity(packageManager) != null) {
            startActivity(intent)
        }
    } catch (ex: Exception) {
        ex.printStackTrace()
        Toast.makeText(this, "Unable to open Map", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
    }

}
```

Comment: Get rid of the `resolveActivity()` calls. You do not need them, as your `catch` blocks will handle any `ActivityNotFoundExceptions` that get raised. If anything, the `resolveActivity()` calls seem like they actively harm your users -- you just quietly do nothing if they do not have a matching app.

Comment: @CommonsWare got your point. That's why it was not showing toast.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem lies in the line of code `intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager())`. When you call resolveActivity, you will get a warning like this:

> Consider adding a  declaration to your manifest when calling this method; see https://g.co/dev/packagevisibility for details

Check the document under [PackageManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager), you will see this note:

> Note: If your app targets Android 11 (API level 30) or higher, the methods in this class each return a filtered list of apps. Learn more about how to manage package visibility.

**So what does that mean?**

In android 11, Google added package visibility policy. Apps now have tighter control over viewing other apps. Your application will not be able to view or access applications outside of your application.

**What do you need to do?**

All you need to do is add below line of code to `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<manifest>
    <queries>
        <intent>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <data android:scheme="geo" />
        </intent>

        <intent>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <data android:scheme="market" />
        </intent>

        <intent>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <data android:scheme="https" />
        </intent>

        <intent>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.DIAL" />
        </intent>
    </queries>
</manifest>
```

More information:

1. [Package visibility in Android 11](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/package-visibility-in-android-11-cc857f221cd9)
2. [Package visibility filtering on Android](https://developer.android.com/training/package-visibility)

Comment: Hey, this solution works perfectly.
Should we add multiple intents in <queries> block if we have multiple intents with same action but different data scheme.

Comment: <queries>
        <intent>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <data android:scheme="geo" />
        </intent>
        
        <intent>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <data android:scheme="market" />
        </intent>
        
        <intent>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <data android:scheme="https" />
        </intent>
 
    </queries>

Comment: @HamzaKhan Yeah. You can have multiple intent queries in an application. As long as you access an application other than your own then you should add `<intent>` query in case you open the application with intent or `<package>` if you open with package name.